# Angular Directive to make selected submenu active as well as it parent and Close all other opened elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

It is two level menu:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#/time'>Time</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/time/timetable'>timetable</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>   
</ul>
```

How can I add **"active"** class to both the item ***"timetable" and its parent "time" based on url***? ( so I can highlight them both ) and removing other previously opened element.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your angular code ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).  I think that is what you are describing.  You can use it to set the element active class based on the current URL or any other data you have available.